# Unix Shell scripting query on sed

Tags: bash, replace, sed, sh

Need a help on unix shell scripting. As I am new to this.

I have a shell script written. While running that script am giving argument as say 003. I need to replace this argument value in a particular line in shell scripts as below.

Script:

```
if [[ $# != 1 ]]

then

        echo "Please enter the Value"
        echo "eg: script.sh 003"
        exit 0;
fi

Q=WMS.XXX.vinoth
```

I need to replace `XXX` value with `003` and append into a temp file. Can you please help me???

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

Do you ask how to replace the XXX with first argument?

```
Q=WMS.$1.vinoth
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the $1 will work, however be aware that you should probably use quotation marks when passing a number like 003 in stead of 3 as in some cases the two zeros in front might be dropped.

Also I recommend wrapping the string in quotation marks as well, avoiding accidental command calls.

```
./script "003"

if [[ $# != 1 ]]

then

        echo "Please enter the Value"
        echo "eg: script.sh 003"
        exit 0;
fi

Q="WMS.$1.vinoth"
```